# Mixed language Client-Server Application, C Client to Python Server, Array of Integers

Tags: python, tcp, c, arrays

I have a **working** C-language TCP client-server application. The C client sends an array of int32 values to the C server. The integer array length varies each time data is sent to the server. I am trying to convert the C server code to Python code. I have not been able to find a python solution for handling the array of variable length as demonstrated by the working C code below.

**C CLIENT Side**

```
// The int32 pointer "data_ptr" holds the array of int32
INT32 *data_ptr = NULL; // initial definition
INT32 data_ptr_size = 1000 // this is an example, value will vary.

// load the int32 values into data_ptr using memcpy or realloc
// send the value of data_ptr_size to Server
// sending the data_ptr to C server, shown below: 

total = 0;
while(total != data_ptr_size*sizeof(INT32)){
    write_cnt = send(hSocket, ((char *)data_ptr+total), (data_ptr_size*sizeof(INT32)-total), 0); 
    total += write_cnt;
    if(write_cnt<1) break;
}
```

**C SERVER Side**

```
// server first receives the value of **data_ptr_size** from client
// server creates memory to store the array of int32
data_ptr = (INT32*)(malloc(data_ptr_size*sizeof(INT32))); 

// server then receives data_ptr (array of int32 values) via socket
total = 0;
read_cnt = 0;
// increment the pointer.
while(total != array_size*sizeof(INT32)){
    read_cnt = recv(sock, ((void *)data_ptr+total), (array_size*sizeof(INT32)-total), 0); 
    total += read_cnt;
    if(read_cnt<1) break;
}
```

At this point all data is loaded as integers and can be used as needed.

Converting the C server to a Python server it appeared that I needed the ctypes library:

```
from ctypes import *

# define a structure like below:
class myArray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("value1", c_uint32),("value2", c_uint32),...]

buff = self.request.recv(sizeof(myArray))
array_in = myArray.from_buffer_copy(buff)
```

However I'm not yet successful in finding a way to dynamically change the size of the structure.
I appreciate your suggestions and sample code.

Thanks

Comment: In general, network protocols should be language-agnostic. To create either side in Python you should not be needing `ctypes` or any "foreign" language interop whatsoever

Comment: Yes, This would be greatly preferred!